# Mixing C with Objective C

Tags: objective-c, c, struct

I'm a little confused as to whats going on in this snippet of example code.
I am creating a property called 'processingGraph' of C struct 'AUGraph'.
I then pass this struct to the Objective C method with 
`[self createAUGraph:_processingGraph];`

I then take this argument...
`- (void) createAUGraph:(AUGraph) graph {
    NewAUGraph (&graph);`
... and create the struct.

However this does not seem to create the struct at the property name '_processingGraph' as I think it should.

Why is this? By passing in a struct to an objective C method, does it just create a copy? Which case, how would I pass a reference to a struct in a method?

Full code:

```
@interface AudioStepper ()
@property (readwrite) AUGraph processingGraph;

@end

@implementation AudioStepper

- (id) init{
if (self = [super init]) {
    [self createAUGraph:_processingGraph];
}
return (self);
}
- (void) createAUGraph:(AUGraph) graph {
NewAUGraph (&graph);
CAShow (_processingGraph); //no struct?
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

graph is not a pointer in your method, so it is getting copied to a new memory location, apart from the original variable. It is like passing in an int or float. This is what is called passing by value.

The C method, however, is using pass by reference. It takes the *pointer* to graph rather than copying the value.

Since this is an ivar, you can access the pointer to _processingGraph directly:

```
- (void) createAUGraph {
    NewAUGraph (&_processingGraph);
    CAShow (_processingGraph);
}
```

Or, if you need to pass in different graphs at different times, you want the method to take a pointer to an AUGraph, use pass by reference:

```
- (void) createAUGraph:(AUGraph*) graph {
    NewAUGraph (graph);     // Since graph is now a pointer, there is no
                            // need to get a pointer to it.
    CAShow (_processingGraph);
}
```

And call the method like so:

```
[self createAUGraph:&_processingGraph];
```

While that fixes the arguments, be sure to read danh's answer below for a better way to create structs.

Comment: Perfect thankyou! Now I understand. Your second answer was what I was after as I need to process different graphs.

Comment: You're welcome. I have added some additional information in my answer about the terminology and why things work this way.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you've accepted an answer.  Glad it's working.  While you were accepting, I was composing this advice, which I think is still good advice....

Take a hint from the objective-c CG structs, like CGPoint, and define your structures this way:

```
// I've made up an AUGraph, since I don't know what yours looks like

typedef struct {
    // whatever is in here, say it's two ints
    int foo;
    int bar;
}AUGraph;
```

Make your properties assign...

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) AUGraph processingGraph;
```

And, most importantly, declare your creation function this way.  (This will be quicker, and read more like the other library functions...

```
static inline AUGraph AUGraphMake(int foo, int bar) {
    AUGraph aug;
    aug.foo = foo;
    aug.bar = bar;
    return aug;
}
```

Here's how a printing function might look...

```
static inline NSString *NSStringFromAUGraph(AUGraph g) {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"AUGraph: foo=%d, bar=%d", g.foo, g.bar];
}
```

Not it looks and feels like native stuff...

```
self.processingGraph = AUGraphMake(3,4);
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromAUGraph(self.processingGraph));
```

Comment: And thank you too. The answers on this page have totally cleared up a long running confusion when mixing c and objective c for me.

Comment: Regarding AUGraphMake, I wish it was declared as you suggest (as it is easier to read), however this is an Apple function from CoreAudio framework.